# An uncommon continued fraction of $\frac{\pi}{2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, pi, continued-fractions

I'm currently stuck with the following infinite continued fraction:
$$\frac{\pi}{2}=1+\dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{1\cdot2}{1+\dfrac{2\cdot3}{1+\dfrac{3\cdot 4}{1+\cdots}}}}$$
There is an obscure clue on this: as one can derive the familiar *Lord Brouncker’s fraction* below
$$
\frac{4}{\pi}=1+\dfrac{1^{2}}{2+\dfrac{3^{2}}{2+\dfrac{5^{2}}{2+\dfrac{7^{2}}{2+\cdots}}}}
$$
from the *Wallis' Formula*:

$$
\dfrac{2}{\pi}=\frac{1 \cdot 3}{2 \cdot 2} \cdot \frac{3 \cdot 5}{4 \cdot 4} \cdot \frac{5 \cdot 7}{6 \cdot 6} \cdot \frac{7 \cdot 9}{8 \cdot 8} \cdots
$$
the first fraction can be proved in the same manner.

However, I'm not getting any close to it using the Wallis' Formula. Really appreciated if anyone could point me the right direction or explain further how to systematically derive those continued fractions from any given convergent cumulative product.

Comment: Could you give a reference for the cfrac you wrote for $\pi/2$ ? Also, where did you find the hint that it related to the Wallis product? Or did you just personally think there was a relation? Thanks. And interesting. +1 on ques.

Comment: The cfrac for $\pi/2$ was obtained when attempting to determine $a_1$ of the sequence $a_{n+1}(a_n-1)=n(n+1)$ where $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n=n+C$. No reference found since that sequence problem was proposed in a chat group. I’ve lost contact with the guy who proposed it but he left that hint on Wallis product. The $pi/2$ answer was derived numerically, just curious about its rigorous proof. 
Abi provided one clear answer below using Euler’s continued fraction. I’m literally new to this field and glad to learn these techniques:)

Comment: Here's something that you can try to use : $\frac{\pi}{2}=\sin^{-1}1$ and we know that Maclaurin series of $\sin^{-1}x=\int1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2n-1}{2^{n+1}}x^{2n}dx$ .

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The result comes from a rather slight modification of [Euler's continued fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_continued_fraction_formula) ,
$$a_{0}+a_{0}a_{1}+a_{0}a_{1}a_{2}+....=\cfrac{a_0}{1-\cfrac{a_1}{1+a_1-\cfrac{a_2}{1+a_2-\cfrac{a_3}{\cdots}}}}\label{1}\tag{1}$$

Note that for a product $a_0a_1a_2\cdots$; we can represent them as,
$$\begin{align}a_{1}a_{2}a_{3}...&=a_{1}+a_{1}\left(a_{2}-1\right)+a_{1}a_{2}\left(a_{3}-1\right)+\cdots\label{2}\tag{2}\end{align}$$
With \eqref{2} in \eqref{1},
$$a_{1}a_{2}a_{3}a_{4}\cdots=1+\cfrac{a_{1}-1}{1-\cfrac{a_{1}\left(a_{2}-1\right)}{a_{2}a_{1}-1-\cfrac{\left(a_{1}-1\right)a_{2}\left(a_{3}-1\right)}{a_{3}a_{2}-1-\cfrac{\left(a_{2}-1\right)a_{3}\left(a_{4}-1\right)}{\cdots}}}}\label{3}\tag{3}$$

Now apply the Wallis product, $$\frac{\pi}{2}=\frac{2\cdot2}{1\cdot3}\cdot\frac{4\cdot4}{3\cdot5}\cdot\frac{6\cdot6}{5\cdot7}\cdots$$
in \eqref{3} with $a_1=2/1$, $a_2=2/3$ ... to get the first result

---

The second result is not obtained via the Wallis product, but from the Leibniz series for $\pi/4$ using \eqref{1}

Comment: Thanks, glad to learn the Euler’ Continued fraction and its application on these products!

Answer (score 1):

We know that $$\sin^{-1}x=\int\underbrace{\color{red}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}}}_{\text{apply binomial theorem}}dx=\int1+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{2n-1}{2^{n+1}}x^{2n}dx$$and if you solve this further you'll get $$\sin^{-1}x=x+
\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{3x^5}{40}+\frac{5x^7}{112}+......$$ $$= x+\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{3}{4}\cdot\frac{x^5}{5}+\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{3}{4}\cdot\frac{5}{6}\cdot\frac{x^7}{7}+......$$ $$=x+x\left(\frac{x^2}{2\cdot3}\right)+x\left(\frac{x^2}{2\cdot3}\right)\left(\frac{(3x)^2}{4\cdot5}\right)+.........$$ OR $$\sin^{-1}x=x\left(1+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\prod_{i=0}^{n}\frac{(2i+1)^2x^2}{(2i+2)\cdot(2i+3)}\right)$$

Now according to *Euler's formula for Continued Fraction* , i.e. $$S=a\left(1+\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\prod_{j=1}^{i}r_j\right)=\large\frac{a}{1-\frac{r_1}{1+r_1-\frac{r_2}{1+r_2-\frac{r_3}{......}}}}$$

So , $$\sin^{-1}x=x\left(1+\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\prod_{i=1}^{n}\frac{(2i-1)^2x^2}{(2i)\cdot(2i+1)}\right)$$ $$=x\Large\left(\frac{1}{1-\frac{\frac{x^2}{2\cdot3}}{1+\frac{x^2}{2\cdot3}-\frac{\frac{3^2x^2}{4\cdot5}}{1+\frac{3^2x^2}{4\cdot5}-.......}}}\right)$$

Since ,  $$\sin^{-1}1=\frac{\pi}{2}$$
Now just put $x=1$ in the above continued fraction to get to your answer .

Comment: The continued fraction obtained here is not the same.

Comment: you need to simplify it further to get there . According to maths its correct .

Comment: @Pi..Mechanic What do you mean by "according to maths". You can have different types of continued fractions for the same quantity. Show us how to simplify it further!

Comment: @Gary by "according to maths" I meant that there's no logical or mathematical error in my solution , so it must be correct .

Comment: And I mean that you may have derived a different type of CF for $\pi/2$ (correctly).

Comment: Yeah that can be a possibility as well.

Comment: But if you derived a different one then you did not answer the question, right? You have to show that it is exactly the one OP was asking about.

Comment: If the question asked for 1+1, and your answer is that 1+3=4, then you're correct, but irrelevant.